# how could I solve "jvi 1.4.3 on netbeans 7.0.1 appear font warn dialog"?

Tags: php, netbeans, fonts, vi, jvi

at first, I'm sorry for my english, hope you understand me..
jVi 1.4.3 plugin on netbeans 7.0.1..
when I click an editor window for the first time I get the following dialog:

=====================================================================================

```
jVi works best with fixed size fonts.

Font size problem for Language: 'PHP (text/x-php5)'

The following specify a variable size font:
                         代码覆盖 - 部分/'PHP (text/x-php5)'
                        代码覆盖 - 未覆盖/'PHP (text/x-php5)'
                          Magic 常量/'PHP (text/x-php5)'
                         代码覆盖 - 覆盖/'PHP (text/x-php5)'
                         代码覆盖 - 推断/'PHP (text/x-php5)'
                                缺省/'`enter code here`
```

=====================================================================================
How can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the jvi plugin. The last RC version has an option for not showing the dialog. The option is on Options/jVI cnfig/Platform/"Font Check disable problem dialog".
BTW, as far as I can tell, that dialog is just a warning, I haven't notice any functionality affected by the fact that one is using a variable size font.